# When does Katrina offer purification after bad luck in ACNH?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I have got bad luck from Katrina several times now, but she never offer me purification services. What am I doing wrong? Does purification needs to be unblocked or am I missing some dialog option?

Comment: Please, refrain from creating and adding useless tags to your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found what was the problem: Katrina will only offer purification if you are carrying enough money (10k bells)

If that is not the case, and that was what was happening to me, then you will never get the purification option offered and will suffer the bad luck effects until the next day